# How to run multiple python scripts to prometheus

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

I have been working on prometheus and Python where I want to be able to have multiple scripts that writes to Promethethus.

Currently I have done 2 scripts:
**sydsvenskan.py**

```
import time

import requests
from prometheus_client import Counter

REQUEST_COUNT = Counter(
    namespace="scraper",
    name="request_count",
    documentation="Count the total requests",
    labelnames=['http_status']
)


def monitor_feed():
    while True:
        with requests.get("https://sydsvenskan.se") as rep:
            print("Request made!")
            REQUEST_COUNT.labels(http_status=rep.status_code).inc()

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_feed()
```

**BBC.py**

```
import time

import requests
from prometheus_client import Counter

REQUEST_COUNT = Counter(
    namespace="scraper",
    name="request_count",
    documentation="Count the total requests",
    labelnames=['http_status']
)


def monitor_feed():
    while True:
        with requests.get("https://bbc.com") as rep:
            print("Request made!")
            REQUEST_COUNT.labels(http_status=rep.status_code).inc()

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_feed()
```

and then I have another script that just starts the promethethus http_server:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8000)
```

however the problem is it seems like nothing goes through the promethethus from the sydsvenskan.py and bbc.py and I wonder what am I doing wrong? I do not see any statistics growing when running the sydsvenskan and bbc at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `start_http_server` function with your `monitor_feed` functions.

You can either combine everything under a single HTTP server.

Or, as I think you want, you'll need to run 2 HTTP servers, one with each `monitor_feed`:

```py
import time
import requests

from prometheus_client import Counter
from prometheus_client import start_http_server


REQUEST_COUNT = Counter(
    namespace="scraper",
    name="request_count",
    documentation="Count the total requests",
    labelnames=['http_status']
)


def monitor_feed():
    while True:
        with requests.get("https://bbc.com") as rep:
            print("Request made!")
            REQUEST_COUNT.labels(http_status=rep.status_code).inc()

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8000)
    monitor_feed()
```

In the latter case, if you run both servers on the same host machine, you'll need to use 2 different ports (you can't use `8000` for both).

Comment: Oh I see. So if I want to use more python instance then I need to add more ports where I give each python instance its own port? If im corrrct?

Comment: Got it! I do hope having 30 ports isnt too much to use!;

Comment: You can always combine the scripts under one process and serve them from one port. It's entirely your choice and depends on how you want to structure your exporter.